Diff between locking and isolations which to use to handle concurrency
I read about the locking mechanisms used in db and isolation. if Locking can solve concurrency problems why we need isolation.
I want to understand the diff between both.
do we need to use both to handle concurrency or isolation level itself can handle concurrency or locking itself can handle concurrency

To ensure data integrity and resolve conflicts on mutating the shared DB state on concurrent access, locks (2PL, MVCC) are required.
However, 2PL (2-Phase-Locking) locking blocks the concurrent users of the DB row from performing read/write operations until the locks are released, and MVCC (Multi-Version Concurrency Control) provides a balance between concurrent access vs. acceptable levels of data anomalies on mutation.
The objective is to promote a certain degree of concurrent access (which increases the application response throughput as well as scalability and reduces the contention) to the shared DB resources at the cost of data integrity (called Phenomena)
SQL-92 introduced the following Phenomena (data anomaly) that can occur as we enable concurrent access:

Dirty Reads
Dirty Writes
Non-Repeatable Reads
Phantom Reads
Read Skews
Write Skews
Lost updates

And there are 4 DB isolation levels (ordered from the least to most restrictive) introduced in SQL-92, that establish the balance of concurrency against data correctness. These isolations specify a level to which a minimum number of phenomena will be prevented:

Read Uncommitted
Read Committed
Repeatable Read
Serializable

Different RDBMS implementations, namely Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, Postgres, and MySQL, provide different levels of isolation.
